# Suppose $M\leq P$ such that $|M|=p^m$, and both $M$ and $P/M$ are cyclic, then there exists $N\leq P$ such that $P=M+N$ and $M\cap N=\{0\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, p-groups

Question: Let $P$ be an abelian $p$-group with exponent $p^m$.  Suppose $M\leq P$ such that $|M|=p^m$, and both $M$ and $P/M$ are cyclic, then there exists $N\leq P$ such that $P=M+N$ and $M\cap N=\{0\}$.

Thoughts: I've wrestled with trying to get the "trivial" cases out of the way first, but, for instance, if $M=P$, then $N$ couldn't even exist, so $M\neq P$.  I've tried thinking about the orders of the groups $M$ and $N$ and tried playing with them, but I must not be doing something right, because I am never using that $M$ and $P/M$ are cyclic, which I'm sure (I suppose) are essential in the question... any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think $N$ cannot exist if $M=P$?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I guess it can.  I was thinking that it would force $N=\{0\}$, but of course that's nonsense now that I think about it.

Comment: Seems like if you choose $x$ such that $M+x$ generates $P/M$, then $N= \langle x \rangle$ has a pretty good chance of working.

Comment: @RobertShore So we have to choose $x\in P-M$ such that $M+x$ generates $P/M$, which we can say that a generator exists, because $M$ and $P/M$ are cyclic.  So that's it..?

Comment: All you need to show that $x$ exists is that $P/M$ is cyclic.  You then have to prove that $N = \langle x \rangle$ has the desired properties.  Some will be obvious.  Some will need you to use your assumptions about $P$ and $M$.

Comment: hmmmm.... Okay, I feel like $P=M+N$ would then be obvious from the way we choose $x$, but I would need to show that $M\cap N=\{0\}$, So could I say that since $|M|=p^m$, so wouldn't $|N|<p^m$?  Hmmmm... I suppose I am just not quite seeing it.

Comment: Try the second homomorphism theorem and work with the order of the various groups in sight.

Comment: $MN/N\cong M/(M\cap N)\implies |M/(M\cap N)|=p^m/|M\cap N|$... would something like this be on the right track?  And use this idea to say something about $M\cap N$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be a generator of $M$, and choose $y \in G$ such that $y+M$ generates $G/M$. Suppose that $|G/M|= p^n$.

Now $p^ny \in M$, and we can write $p^ny = bp^kx$ for some $b$ and $k$ with $\gcd(b,p)=1$.

Then the order of $y$ is the  product of $p^n$ and the order of $bp^kx$, which is $p^{m-k}$, so ${\rm ord}(y) = p^{n+m-k}$. But we are told that $G$ has exponent $p^m$, so $n+m-k \le m$ and hence $n \le k$.

So $p^n(y-bp^{k-n}x) = 0$, and hence the subgroup $N$ of $G$ generated by $y-bp^{k-n}x$ satisfies $M+N=G$ and $M \cap N = \{0\}$.